# Generate Random Speed letters for Race Game in C#

Tags: c#, console-application

I am creating a simple task just to keep practicing. Now I created a  non-interactive game. And the letter are the characters which is A, B, C. Now since I've position my 'C' to 3 it is always the first one to finish. How do you random the speed of each characters?

```
static void Main()
        {
           

          Runner runnerA = new Runner('A');   
            Runner runnerB = new Runner('B');
            Runner runnerC = new Runner('C');

            runnerA.Position = 1;
            runnerB.Position = 3;
            runnerC.Position = 3;

            string course = "---......------.......";

            while (true)
            {
                runnerA.Position++;
                runnerB.Position++;
                runnerC.Position++;

                if (runnerA.Position == course.Length)
                {
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < course.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (runnerA.Position == i)
                    {
                        Console.Write(runnerA.Glyph);
                    }
                    else if (runnerB.Position == i)
                    {
                        Console.Write(runnerB.Glyph);
                    }
                    else if (runnerB.Position == i) {
                        Console.Write(runnerB.Glyph);
                    }
                    else // No runners on this tile.
                    {
                        Console.Write(course[i]);
                    }
                }

                Console.Write('|');

                Console.WriteLine();

                Thread.Sleep(100);
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);


            }

            
        }
    }
```

Comment: That one ain't there anymore; it's been deleted

Comment: Yes. apologize for that

Comment: There's a lot of _not there_ in your code. What purpose does `strin course` have? I kinda understand, but... what's does `Runner `look like exactly? If you want to have random speed, you are probably going to want a longer course. Take a look at `System.Random`. Use a single instance to generate a random distance for each _runner_ to advance on each turn. Alternatively. You could use a `Random` instance to roll a die to decide if a runner advances or not

Comment: the string course is the track field of the race. the dot(.) kinda acts as a mud thing and the dash(-) symbol act as a normal road. they require also a different speed

Comment: I am just trying to do more exercise to enhance my problem solving skill but this time. I really got stuck. I have this problem for the past 3 weeks. I can't solve it that is why I am here now

Answer (score 1):

You have two else if conditions that are the same for the runnerB position. I assume that you meant that the second of them will be runnerC. I changed this, and I changed so that the position of the runners will be random in the range of the last position to end of the course string. Each random position is different from previous positions. for many runners we may think for a more efficient solution.

```
static void main()
{
    Runner runnerA = new Runner('A');
    Runner runnerB = new Runner('B');
    Runner runnerC = new Runner('C');
    Random rand = new Random();

    runnerA.Position = 1;
    runnerB.Position = 2;
    runnerC.Position = 3;

    string course = "---......------.......";

    while (true)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < course.Length; i++)
        {
            if (runnerA.Position == i)
            {
                Console.Write(runnerA.Glyph);
            }
            else if (runnerB.Position == i)
            {
                Console.Write(runnerB.Glyph);
            }
            else if (runnerC.Position == i)
            {
                Console.Write(runnerC.Glyph);
            }
            else // No runners on this tile.
            {
                Console.Write(course[i]);
            }
        }

        Random rand = new Random();
        runnerA.Position = rand.Next(runnerA.Position, course.Length);
        do
         runnerB.Position = rand.Next(runnerB.Position, course.Length);
        while (runnerB.Position == runnerA.Position);

        do
         runnerC.Position = rand.Next(runnerC.Position, course.Length);
        while (runnerC.Position == runnerA.Position || runnerC.Position 
        == runnerB.Position);    
        Console.Write('|');

        Console.WriteLine();

        Thread.Sleep(100);
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which works like this:

- **Runner** classes are instantiated with random positions and speeds
- Runners have a Timer property which allows to indicate when they need to be moved according to the elapsed time
- I made a speed factor appear depending on the terrain: 1 if "-" and 0.5 if "."
- If two runners have the same position, only one will appear

The **Main** void:

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        string map = "-----------............------..............-----------............|";
        int interval = 50;
        List<Runner> runners = new List<Runner>
        {
            new Runner('A', random.Next(1, 10), random.Next(1, 5) * interval),
            new Runner('B', random.Next(1, 10), random.Next(1, 5) * interval),
            new Runner('C', random.Next(1, 10), random.Next(1, 5) * interval)
        };

        while (true)
        {
            foreach (Runner runner in runners)
            {
                if (runner.Position == map.Length - 1)
                {
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 1);
                    Console.WriteLine($"The winner is: {runner.Glyph} !");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                double mapFactor = map[runner.Position].Equals('-') ? 1 : 0.5;
                runner.Update(interval, mapFactor);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < map.Length; i++)
            {
                Runner matchingRunner = runners.Find(x => x.Position == i);
                Console.Write(matchingRunner != null ? matchingRunner.Glyph : map[i]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Thread.Sleep(interval);
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

And the associated **Runner** class:

```
public class Runner
{
    public char Glyph { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public int Speed { get; set; }
    public int Timer { get; set; }

    public Runner(char glyph, int position, int speed)
    {
        Glyph = glyph;
        Position = position;
        Speed = speed;
        Timer = 0;
    }

    public void Update(int interval, double mapFactor)
    {
        Timer += interval;
        if (Timer / mapFactor > Speed)
        {
            Timer = 0;
            Position++;
        }
    }
}
```